# Fineuploader - OnComplete Method can't call a value outside the function

Tags: angular

I have a problem with fineuploader in the `OnComplete()` function when I try to call "customer" value inside it. I'm using Angular and TypeScript for frontside.

The "customer" value is undefined because it is not found in the `onComplete()` bloc (no auto-completion). So how can I call my `importCustomers` function? any idea?

Thank you in advance for any help.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an issue with `this` scoping

```
ngAfterViewInit(){

var self = this; //<-- assign this before setting the new Uploader class

this.uploader = new Uploader({

....

   self.customer.importCustomers(name); //<-- use the assigned self here

}
```

Comment: @amin89 I don't think you are doing the same thing as my answer. Can you double check? Assign `self` to `this` just before the `new` assignment.

Comment: I've added var self = this outside the "export class Import component" and didn't work. I've tested it inside the ngAfterInitMethod and not work too .. and called  "self.customer.importCustomers(name);"  Strange

Comment: Ok problem with cache I think. No error now. thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow functions since they [have no binding of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
onComplete = (id, name, responseJSON) => {
  if(responseJSON.success) {
    console.log("Upload done")
    this.customer.importCustomers(name)
  }
}
```

Alternatively you can pass `this` on your function arguments :

```
onComplete(id, name, responseJSON, this) {
  let _this = this;
  if(responseJSON.success) {
    console.log("Upload done")
    _this.customer.importCustomers(name)
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: What do you mean ? I posted how the code should be.

Comment: Sorry, i've didn't seen your answer. I can't pass this directly in the method.

Comment: Did you try the arrow function ?